# JustMock: Mocking Static method call not working

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, justmock

Using JustMock:

I am not sure why my arrange call for a static method is trying to execute the original.

```
[Test] 
public void RunCompleteDivxJob_Negative_Exception()
{
    DebugView.IsTraceEnabled = true;
    var mediaId = 2000999;
    var mediaTypeId = (int)CmtMediaType.Video;
    var queueCmtId = 9999;
    var cmtFileType = CmtFileType.SourceMediaFile;
    var statusError = CmtQueueStatus.Error;
    var exception = new Exception("test");

    // ARRANGE
    var encodeJobStateMachineManager = Mock.Create<EncodeJobStateMachineManager>(Behavior.CallOriginal);
    var logger = Mock.Create<Logger>(Behavior.CallOriginal, typeof(EncodeJobStateMachineManager));
    var inst = new PrivateAccessor(encodeJobStateMachineManager);
    inst.SetProperty("_log", logger);
    var createCompleteJobCalled = false;
    Mock.Arrange(() => DivxEncodeJob.CreateCompleteJob(mediaId, mediaTypeId, queueCmtId, cmtFileType))
    .DoInstead(() => createCompleteJobCalled = true);
    Mock.Arrange(() => encodeJobStateMachineManager.EncodeJob.Submit()).Throws(exception).MustBeCalled();
    logger.Arrange(x => x.Error(Arg.AnyString, exception)).MustBeCalled();
    //Mock.SetupStatic(typeof(QueueDAO));
    var updateQueueStatusCalled = false;
    Mock.Arrange(() => QueueDAO.UpdateQueueStatus(queueCmtId, statusError)).DoInstead(() =>  updateQueueStatusCalled = true);

    // ACT
    encodeJobStateMachineManager.RunCompleteDivxJob(mediaId, mediaTypeId, queueCmtId, cmtFileType);

    // ASSERT
    Mock.Assert(encodeJobStateMachineManager);
    Assert.IsTrue(createCompleteJobCalled);
    Assert.IsTrue(updateQueueStatusCalled);
}
```

The first static call is mocking the method call correctly:

```
Mock.Arrange(() => DivxEncodeJob.CreateCompleteJob(mediaId, mediaTypeId, queueCmtId, cmtFileType))
            .DoInstead(() => createCompleteJobCalled = true);
```

But the second static call is executing the original code:

```
Mock.Arrange(() => QueueDAO.UpdateQueueStatus(queueCmtId, statusError)).DoInstead(() => updateQueueStatusCalled = true);
```

These are essentially called exactly the same.  So why is the first one working as expected and the second not?

Comment: How is `statusError` being passed to `QueueDAO.UpdateQueueStatus`?

Comment: as an enum?  not sure what you mean by "how"?

Answer (score 0):

The likely problem is that `QueueDAO.UpdateQueueStatus` is not called with the expected arguments. Check if adding the `.IgnoreArguments()` clause to its arrangement will make it work. If yes, then it's a problem with the arguments.

Use the debugger to double-check exactly what arguments the method is called with. Alternatively you can watch `DebugView.FullTrace` in the debugger, browse down to the interception of the `QueueDAO.UpdateQueueStatus` call and see what arguments it's called with and why no arrangement was chosen for the call.